# If every cubic micrometer of ocean water is a potential living cell, then how probable is abiogenisis given the size of the world's oceans?

Tags: statistics

I looked it up. A small living cell is $1$ cubic micrometer. It looks like we have $1.3 \times 10^{36}$ cubic micrometers of water in the world's oceans. Assume the entire ocean happens to have all elements needed for life (not molecules, just elements) (carbon, hydrogen, nitrogen, oxygen, phosphorus and sulphur).

Let's go with that saying that those chemicals coming to life is like a monkey typing the entire works of Shakespeare. That's approximately $5748736$ characters. Let's say an interesting chemical reaction can happen every quarter second.

So $1.3 \times 10^{36}$ monkeys typing, $4$ letters per second. How long before one types a predetermined string of $5748736$ characters?

Comment: "Let's say an interesting chemical reaction can happen every quarter second" : you will need to be more explicit here.  Given a fixed cubic micrometer, and a fixed length of time (say 1 second, or 1/4 second), what is the explicit probability that the necessary reaction occurs in that specific location, in that specific time interval?  Also, is it to be assumed that such possible events are *independent* of each other, with a fixed location, but with longer time intervals?  Similarly, are such possible events *independent* of each other with a fixed time window but different locations?

Comment: If time goes by and the next letter doesn't get typed then something has to happen that destroyed the previous few letters. But typing any incorrect letter destroys the whole document anyway. So the existing chemicals getting destroyed is no different than the monkey typing any incorrect letter. Like if there where a "discard document" key it would be no different than typing any other incorrect key. (There's no backspace and retype.)

Comment: Let's assume that the proximity probability part is built into all those letters in Shakespeare (although you're probably correct that life is more difficult than a monkey typing Shakespeare).

Comment: [Actual monkeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem#Actual_monkeys) do not type at random.  And some people might be satisfied if the monkeys produced the complete works with the plays or sonnets in a different order.

Comment: @Henry, Random number generators aren't random either. Everything has a cause unless it is a quantum level event. Regardless, monkeys was just a metaphor. It's actually unlikely they'd type much at all and more likely break the typewriters.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do the same calculation that [Wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem), which considers predetermined non-overlapping blocks of text to be candidates for the works of Shakespeare, rather than considering every block of length 5748736 to be a candidate, which makes the calculation significantly harder due to non-independence of the events.

So instead of 4 characters every second, we consider blocks of 5748736 characters every $\frac{5748736}{4} = 1437184$ seconds. Let's write $\Delta t = 1437184$ seconds, $N = 1.3 \cdot 10^{36}$ for the number of cubic micrometers of water, $n$ for the number of $\Delta t$-periods elapsed, $S = 5748736$ the length of Shakespeare's works in characters, and $c = 50$ the (approximate) number of characters on a keyboard. Then a single cubic micrometer in a single $\Delta t$ period has a probability of
$$1- \frac{1}{c^S} = 1-\frac{1}{50^{5748736}}$$
of failing generating the entire works of Shakespeare. The probability of $N$ independent cubic micrometers of water failing to generate the works of Shakespeare in a single $\Delta t$ time period is
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{c^S}\right)^N. $$
Similarly, after $n$ of the $\Delta t$ time periods, the probability of failing to generate the works of Shakespeare is
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{c^S}\right)^{Nn} = \left(1-\frac{1}{c^S}\right)^{c^S \cdot\frac{Nn}{c^S}} \approx e^{-\frac{Nn}{c^S}}, $$
now incorporating the standard approximation for $e^x$. Say we want to set this probability equal to $0.5$. Then we simply solve
$$-\frac{Nn}{c^S} = \ln 0.5 = -\ln 2,$$
$$n = \frac{c^S \ln 2}{N} = \frac{50^{5748736} \ln 2}{1.3 \cdot 10^{36}} \approx 5.67 \cdot 10^{9766893}$$
FWIW $\Delta t$ is about 16 days, but it doesn't really matter how long $\Delta t$ is - even if it were only one second this would be dramatically longer than the lifetime of the known universe. I'm guessing removing the non-overlapping blocking of the text would reduce the estimate of time by an order of magnitude or two - not enough to make this a reasonable amount of time elapsed.

Suffice to say that either (1) this can't be a good model of abiogenesis, or (2) abiogenesis really is a monumentally rare event and we shouldn't expect to see life elsewhere in the universe for that reason alone.

Comment: First thx for this. (I'm awful at stats.) I was going to say overlapping was fine. I.e. if a bunch of useless chemical reactions happened they would probably fall apart. They would not need to be reset in some way for useful chemical reactions to start. That probably makes a big difference.